# which is more efficient to select the elements taht are common in two list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-in

If I have two list and I want to create a new third list that has only the  common elements in the two list (a where in query) can use this code:

```
var listC = listB.Join(listA, b => b.ObjectAId, a => a.Id, (b, a) => b).ToList();
```

This way has an O(n) complexity.

However, I also can use a select method in this way:

```
var lstC = listA.Where(r => listB.Contains(r).ToList();
```

This second way is O(n) too?

If the two ways has the same efficient, which differences are between both of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var listC = listA.Intersect(listB); // perhaps a .ToList() on the end
```

This will use hashing to keep it as cheap as possible.

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
var commonElements = listA.Intersect(listB).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) function, which takes two lists and turns them into one which has all the elements that are in both lists. There is also an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you want the equality of the objects not to be based on reference equality/default `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your class.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
var commonElements = listA.Intersect(listB); 
//you can add an IEqualityComparer<T> to the arguments,
//or append .ToList()/.ToArray to make it a list/array.
```